# Issue doing print_r to array and echo on array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, printing, foreach, echo

I have a long object stored in an array. I am trying to display an specifics values of this array.

The problem is the following:

---

```
foreach($reportVal["OrderEventDetail"] AS $OrderEventDetailK => $OrderEventDetailV){
  print_r($reportVal["OrderEventDetail"]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
       [eventId] => 18345
       [orderId] => 781 
      )


Array ( 
      [eventId] => 18345 
      [orderId] => 781 
       )
```

---

Everything is ok at this point, but:

---

```
foreach($reportVal["OrderEventDetail"] AS $OrderEventDetailK => $OrderEventDetailV){
  $OrderEventDetailV["orderId"];
}
```

Output:

```
1 7
```

---

Why its happening? If im printing ["orderId"], the value would be 781 781.

Expected result:

```
<span class="label label-success" style="background-color: #5cb85c;">Orden <?= $OrderEventDetailV["orderId"] ?></span>
```

With value:

```
<span class="label label-success" style="background-color: #5cb85c;">Orden 781</span>
```

Comment: What are you expecting from just single `$OrderEventDetailV["orderId"];` in loop body?

Comment: I just **edited your code** to add the necessary `print_r` that many comments and answers have indicated must be there.  Can you please confirm whether this solves the problem?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum, editors **should not** modify the OP's code (only minor formatting is allowed). Use comments or your own answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to echo `$reportVal["OrderEventDetail"]["orderId"];`

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want to be doing a

```
print_r($OrderEventDetailV["orderId"]);
```

in your loop?

Comment: No. the array is $reportVal["OrderEventDetail"], i want the value in $OrderEventDetailV["orderId"] key.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This Code**

```
echo "<pre>";
foreach($reportVal["OrderEventDetail"] AS $OrderEventDetailK => $OrderEventDetailV)
{
  print_r($OrderEventDetailV["orderId"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Array ( 
       [eventId] => "18345"
       [orderId] => "781" 
      )


Array ( 
      [eventId] => "18345"
      [orderId] => "781" 
       ) 

foreach($reportVal["OrderEventDetail"] AS $OrderEventDetailK => $OrderEventDetailV){
  $OrderEventDetailV["orderId"];
}
```